# Copy data from one worksheet and put it to the other right worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy cell E10 from a worksheet called "Overview" and paste it to cell D1 in all of the other Worksheets to the right of the "Overview" worksheet. Below is the code I have come up with. My issue is that this code executes for all worksheets, including the ones to the left of "Overview". Is there a way to have the code recognize to start to the right of "Overview"?

```
Sub Newthing()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

Worksheets("Overview").Range("E10").Copy
Worksheets(i).Range("D1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next i

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: `For i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").Index + 1 to ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count`

Comment: you are the man! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

### Copy to Next Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Newthing()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Overview")
    
    ' Get the next (first) and last worksheet indices.
    Dim wsLast As Long: wsLast = wb.Worksheets.Count ' last worksheet index
    Dim wsNext As Long: wsNext = ws.Index + 1 ' next worksheet index
    
    ' Prevent error if 'ws' is the last worksheet.
    If wsNext > wsLast Then
        MsgBox "'" & ws.Name & "' is the last worksheet.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the value to a variable instead of reading it multiple times
    ' from the worksheet.
    Dim cValue As Variant: cValue = ws.Range("E10").Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Copy by assignment (only values):
    For i = wsNext To wsLast
        wb.Worksheets(i).Range("D1").Value = cValue
    Next i

End Sub
```